# How to minimize cell height in CSS grids?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid set up here

https://codepen.io/sneaky666/pen/zYBQRxj

```css
#A {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(6, max-content);
}
#A > div {
  padding:10px;
}
#A > div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column:1 / 1;  
}
#A > div:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row:1 / 1;
}
#A > div:nth-child(-n+6) {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
}
#A > div:nth-child(n+7) {
  grid-column:4 / 5;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
</div>
```

Where I want the first 6 items to load in a 3x2 grid on the left side. And then the remaining items to load on the right side vertically as the 4th column. However I also want it so that the height of the cells in the 4th column only spans the content, it shouldn't get aligned to the cells on the left part.

In this example you can see that I set the height of the red cells to be 200px to make it large, however the green cells (4th column) height is not altered, however it is extending and making it bigger to align with the red cells. I would like it to be shrunk to fit the content for the green cells.

How can I fix this? I am looking for a pure css solution preferably in css grids.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kind of the point of a grid is to keep it together like that.  You get around it by creating 2 grids side by side if that works for you.  Take a look at what I did in this example. Hope it works for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/ecsuakft/

```css
#A {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows:repeat(6, max-content);
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}
#A > div {
  padding:10px;
}
#A > div:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column:1 / 1;  
}
#A > div:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row:1 / 1;
}
#A > div:nth-child(-n+6) {
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
}
#B > div:nth-child(n) {

  background-color:green;
}

#B {
  display: grid;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  </div>
<div id="B">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the div structure must remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

I only see `position:absolute` that can do this. CSS grid clearly cannot do this (flexbox too)

```css
#A {
  padding-left:calc(3*100%/4);
  position:relative;
  min-height:400px;
}
#A > div {
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#A > div:nth-child(-n+6) {
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  width:calc(100%/4);
  height:200px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#A > div:nth-child(2),
#A > div:nth-child(5) {left:25%}
#A > div:nth-child(3),
#A > div:nth-child(6) {left:50%}
#A > div:nth-child(4),
#A > div:nth-child(5),
#A > div:nth-child(6) {transform:translateY(100%)}

#A > div:nth-child(n+7) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
</div>
```